# Qt calculate age from a QDate

Tags: qt

I have a birthdate stored as QDate and I would like to kown how many years the person has.
I've tried the daysTo() function but then I cannot convert days in years.
How can I do?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdate.html#year-1 doesn't work for you?

Comment: This function returns the year of the QDate. For example 2022-07-11 is returning 2022. In my case I need 0 as return value.

Comment: int age = QDate::currentDate().year() - date.year();

Comment: Not working, if my birthdate is 1995-07-12 it returns 27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to do this:

```
int age(const QDate &birthday)
{
    const auto today = QDate::currentDate();
    auto age = today.year() - birthday.year();
    return today.month() >= birthday.month() && today.day() >= birthday.day() ? age : age - 1;
}
```